# Building a string using symbols

Tags: c++, c, string

In python, I'm able to build a string using this method:

```
>>> s = "%s is my name" %("Joe")
>>> s
'Joe is my name'
```

Is there a similar way to do this in C++? I know C has

```
printf("%s is my name", "Joe")
```

But that's for printing to standard out. Ideally I'd like something like the Python example. Thanks!

EDIT: Is there a name for this kind of thing? I couldn't think of what to google!

Comment: Take a look at [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf)

Comment: The name you're looking for is probably "format".

Comment: Since you tagged your question as C++, take a look at [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sprintf command works like printf, but has an extra parameter at the front. The first parameter is an array of characters of where to store the string instead of printing it.

```
char chararray[1000];
sprintf(chararray,"%s is my name","Joe");
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/